# Combine concat values from 2 columns to one cell

Tags: sql, oracle

my query need to concat 2 columns then sort according to ID in one cell seperated by ; from a table.

this is my table:

```
ID  Name  Contact_type  Contact_number
1    ALEX   Mobile         12313
2    ALEX   OfficeNumber   879879
3    FLYNN  Mobile           12342
4    FLYNN  OfficeNumber     656757
```

I have tried pivot two columns : Contact_type and contact_number. But i had a hard time putting them together in a cell and the pivot result did not meet my needs.

```
select a.ID, a.Name, a.contact_type ||':'|| a.contact_number
from e_address a
```

i need output :

```
ID  Name  Contacts
1    ALEX  Mobile:12313;OfficeNumber:879879
2    FLYNN  Mobile:12342;OfficeNumber:656757
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation as `listagg()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(id) as id,
       a.Name,
       listagg(a.contact_type ||':'|| a.contact_number, ';') within group (order by a.contact_type) as contacts
from e_address a
group by a.name;
```

Note that you have changed the `id` column for the data.  That seems potentially awkward.  Perhaps you really want `min(id)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with simple `listagg()` group by:

```
select a.ID
     , a.Name
     , listagg(a.contact_type ||':'|| a.contact_number, ';') within group(order by a.contact_type ||':'|| a.contact_number) as Contacts
  from e_address a
 group by a.ID, a.Name
```

Comment: Note that ID is different for each row of the source table. So `group by a.ID, a.Name` will produce **four rows** not two. This is due to lack of clarity in OP's question but probably they want some kind of rownum for ID.